# Jmeter- How to manipulate DateTime Type Variable?

Tags: csv, jmeter, jexl

We need to add n Minutes to a work order start time variable (WOStartTime)  for every sample, what are possible ways?

Currently we are using jexl function in jp@gc - Parameterized Controller;

```
${__jexl(${__threadNum()}*8 + ${WOStartTime})}
```

where WOStartTime is a datetime fetched from a CSV file;

and getting following exception;
**2014/05/20 15:44:11 ERROR - jmeter.functions.JexlFunction: An error occurred while evaluating the expression "1*8 + 5/20/2004 15:05"
 org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ParseException: Encountered "15" at line 1, column 17.
Was expecting one of:
    "||" ...
    "or" ...
    "&&" ...
    "and" ...
    "|" ...
    "^" ...
    "&" ...
    "==" ...
    "eq" ...
    "!=" ...
    "ne" ...
    "<" ...
    "lt" ...
    ">" ...
    "gt" ...
    "<=" ...
    "le" ...
    ">=" ...
    "ge" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "*" ...
    "/" ...
    "div" ...
    "%" ...
    "mod" ...
    ";" ...
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.Parser.generateParseException(Parser.java:4176)**

We have added a BeanShell Preprocessor to manipulate datetime variable;

```
woStartDate=vars.get("WOStartTime");
StartTime=vars.get("Start");
EndTime=vars.get("End");


Date NewStartTime ; 


if (StartTime == null){
    StartTime =woStartDate;
    print("StartTime == null");
}
else    {
    NewStartTime=StartTime;
    NewStartTime.setTime(NewStartTime.getTime()+2); 
    StartTime=NewStartTime;

}


print(StartTime);

vars.put("Start", StartTime);

    EndTime=StartTime;
    EndTime.setTime(NewStartTime.getTime()+5); 
vars.put("End", EndTime);
```

**StartTime is always NULL** , but after **vars.put("Start", StartTime)** for second sample this should not be NULL, need help to resolve the issue;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're having issues with your Beanshell script.

1. JMeter variables come as String, you need to cast them to Date
2. `+2` and `+5` operators are adding milliseconds, not minutes
3. If one of variables in first 3 lines will be not set your script won't go on.

Refer to updated script below for details and corrections:

```
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Date;

    vars.put("WOStartTime", "1970-01-01 12:00");
    vars.put("Start", "1970-01-01 12:00");
    vars.put("End", "1970-01-01 12:00");
    Date woStartDate = null;
    Date StartTime = null;
    Date EndTime = null;

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm");

    try {
        woStartDate = sdf.parse(vars.get("WOStartTime"));
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        System.err.println("WOStartTime is not defined");
    }
    try {
        StartTime = sdf.parse(vars.get("Start"));
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        System.err.println("Start variable is not defined");
    }
    try {
        EndTime = sdf.parse(vars.get("End"));
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        System.err.println("End variable is not defined");
    }


    Date NewStartTime = null;


    if (StartTime == null) {
        StartTime = woStartDate;
        System.out.println(("StartTime == null"));
    } else {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(StartTime);
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);
        NewStartTime = cal.getTime();
        StartTime = NewStartTime;

    }


    System.out.println(StartTime);

    vars.put("Start", sdf.format(StartTime));

    EndTime = StartTime;
    if (NewStartTime != null) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(StartTime);
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
        EndTime = cal.getTime();
    }
    vars.put("End", sdf.format(EndTime));
```

If you add a [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) you'll see something like:

```
JMeterVariables:
JMeterThread.last_sample_ok=true
End=1970-07-01 12:07
Start=1970-02-01 12:02
WOStartTime=1970-01-01 12:00
```

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more Beanshell tips and tricks.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because you are not getting correctly the StartTime. You can use

> User Defined Variable

and you put into your StartTime and after that you can use it in your BeanShell like that

```
StartTime="${Start}"
```

Then use java code to convert and get the format date you want for example:

```
import java.text.DateFormat; 
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; 
import java.text.ParseException; 
import java.util.Date; 


SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy:HH:mm"); 

Date OriginalDepositDate = format.parse("${datePlanificationService}"); 
long dateConverti=OriginalDepositDate.getTime();
return dateConverti;
```

I hope that this will help

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, java.text.SimpleDateFormat formatter = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy") works, but java.text.SimpleDateFormat formatter = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"); does not work; Another issue seems to be with import, i am unable to import therefor I m using fully qualified names.

Comment: you are welcome, maybe the problem is with the format you specified, try to use this format ("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), you are using beanShell Sampler?